# Autocomplete on dynamically created inputs

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried to incorporate the answers given else where on this topic, but they don't seem to work for me. Chances are I'm doing it wrong... All I want to do is what it says in the title. I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22u42/) of what I have so far. Any help would be much appreciated.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22u42/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="newlink">
    <div>
        <input id="stores[]" class="stores" placeholder="Start typing code or name of item">
        <input name="itemcount[]" type="tel" placeholder="Quantity" value="" maxlength="5" />
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
 <h2 id="addnew">
<a class="add" href="javascript:new_link()">Add Line</a>

<div id="newlinktpl" style="display: none">
    <div>
        <input id="stores[]" class="stores" placeholder="Start typing code or name of item">
        <input name="itemcount[]" type="tel" placeholder="Quantity" value="" maxlength="5"/>
     <br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var choices = [
        "Pizza",
        "Fries",
        "Milkshake"];

    $('.stores').autocomplete({
        source: choices,
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () {}
        }
    });
});


var ct = 1;
function new_link() {
    ct++;
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ct;

    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? It works fine, it just needs a bit more style on the drop down.

Comment: Add a class on your new created dom, like ``div1.addClass("autocomplete");`` (jquery) or ``div1.className += "autocomplete";`` (vanilla). Then listen for an input change and call your autocompletion function like you would normally do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22u42/2/)**

You need to assign the event each time you create a new input field. So that how you can do this:

```
var choices;
$(function () {
    choices = [
        "Pizza",
        "Fries",
        "Milkshake"];

    autocomplete();
});

function autocomplete(){
 $('.stores').autocomplete({
        source: choices,
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () {}
        }
    });
}

var ct = 1;
function new_link() {
    ct++;
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = ct;

    div1.innerHTML = document.getElementById('newlinktpl').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('newlink').appendChild(div1);
    autocomplete();

}
```